# GravityForms inside Gantry4 won't display

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

Implementing GravityForms inside a the Gantry4 Template works fine until inserting the form to a page. The form (which includes conditionals) is not displayed in the public view of the page.

After 7 hours of research seems the problem comes from the theme (Gantry4) as changing it for another theme does display the form, but support team for GravityForms don't give any direct solution, they rather recommend to change the theme.

Trying to change the theme to Gantry5 seems to be a matter of days, and can't be sure the problem would be solved (as maybe the problem comes because of the use of mootools), and as no error appears on the console it's almost impossible to find the real cause.

Making some tests with the console it all seems to be a problem with the jQuery.bind() which is not binding the function for forms with conditionals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After almost surrendering to the problem, and waiting to get an answer from other users in here, I tryed another possibility...

Changing the page-template for the default additional option in Gantry4 (Contact Form) displayed the form without any problem! (with a contact form at the bottom of course).

So I just made a copy of that page-template and just changed the title and deactivated the load of the `contactform` leaving the `mainbody` empty like this:

```
echo $gantry->displayMainbody();
```

Don't know if it's the correct approach but that solved the issue.

Comment: Glad you could resolve the issue. Since your theme seems to be a bit special it probably would have been easier to contact their support (not Gravity Forms).

Answer (score 0):

Did you update a theme or plugin as well? It looks like you have an issue where something is stripping out shortcodes. Can you go into HTML view in your page and double check that the embed code still looks correct? If so, can you follow these troubleshooting steps to identify the problem?

http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Testing_for_a_Theme/Plugin_Conflict

Comment: We indeed made those tests, it seemed to be a problem in the theme, as I stated on the second paragraph.